# How to change background image of body after ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing an ajax request and when it completes I want to change the background image of the body element to be a certain theme. The theme is just a number 1 - 5.

I have tried:

```
document.body.style.background = "url('images/" + theme + "/background.jpg')";
```

and

```
$("body").css('background-image', `url(images/${theme}/background.jpg)`);
```

and

```
$("body").css('background-image', 'url(images/' + theme + '/background.jpg)');
```

and

```
$("body").css('background-image', 'url("images/' + theme + '/background.jpg")');
```

None of these work. If I hard code in the url it works:

```
$("body").css('background-image', 'url(images/1/background.jpg)');
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have u made sure codes get called after all the ajax requests are done?

Comment: No I don't think so. That's probably it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that your `theme` variable might have the wrong value. Try a `console.log('theme: ' + theme);` to check.

Also you can look in the developer console to see if any 404 errors are reported. Check the url being called for your image.

NB: if your `theme` variable is an object, then convert to the required string.

You can verify that `theme` is correct. If it's expected to be a number then try this:

`$("body").css('background-image', 'url("images/' + theme.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') + '/background.jpg")');`

Comment: If I print out console.log('url("images/' + theme + '/background.jpg")') I get url("images/4/background.jpg") but it splits it into 2 lines after the 4

Comment: Ok. there's a space in there.. need to trim the `theme` variable

Comment: The space was there because it prints it to a new line. No space in the console log

Comment: ok, then try this `theme.replace(/[\n\s]/g, '')` So like `$("body").css('background-image', 'url("images/' + theme.replace(/[\n\s]/g, '') + '/background.jpg")');` (i.e. if there are no spaces in the various theme names... otherwise leave out the `\s` in the `replace`

Comment: The theme names are single digits.

Comment: If you know your theme is always going to be a number, then use this expression `$("body").css('background-image', 'url("images/' + theme.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') + '/background.jpg")');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163220/discussion-between-signal2013-and-grabury).

Comment: Thanks for that!! The theme names had spaces and or new line characters

Comment: Thanks.. I updated my answer based on your debug info.